# What are good guidelines to avoid getting locked by twitter API with a newly created bot?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have finished creating a bot and got blocked 1 minute after I finally got it to work. The account is now restricted.

this is what I get on my terminal if I try to run the bot now:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform.', 'code': 261}]
```

I understand Twitter may restrict new bots for several reasons. I have summited my report to try and get my account unrestricted.

What are good do and don'ts for bots?

In my original bot I was replying every 10s was this too much ? Should I had set a different time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits

Relevant parts:

> Tweets: 2,400 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as Tweets.

> These limits include actions from all devices, including web, mobile, phone, API, etc. API requests from all third-party applications are tracked against the hourly API limit. People who use multiple third-party applications with their account will therefore reach the API limit more quickly.

> What happens if I hit a limit?
> If you do reach a limit, we'll let you know with an error message telling you which limit you've hit. For limits that are time-based (like the Direct Messages, Tweets, changes to account email, and API request limits), you'll be able to try again after the time limit has elapsed.

10 seconds is too much.